# Run part of Python unit tests on remote Linux machine from a Windows host

Tags: python, linux, windows, pytest, xdist

My situation goes like this:

- I have a windows-based server program and a linux-based client.
- I have many tests for the linux clients which run and are required to run on local linux machines
- I need to run some code from windows server machine which will send some messages to the linux clients. Then, a test shall be executed on linux client machines which verifies the effect of those messages

So a typical test case would look like this, running on windows host:

```
test_example_message(self):
    # has to be executed locally on windows server
    send_message(EXAMPLE, hosts)
    # has to be executed locally on linux clients
    for host in hosts:
        verify_message_effect(EXAMPLE, host)
```

I have found that **pytest-xdist** is somehow able to do that.

I there any good tutorial or code example on how to use it?

Comment: some resources I've found so far:  
[xdist & django](http://tech.marksblogg.com/faster-django-testing.html) ;;;   
[intro to py.test](http://merlinux.eu/~hpk/ep2013-pytest.pdf)

Comment: anothore one (in Czech): [horejsek.blog] (http://blog.horejsek.com/co-se-mi-libi-na-pytestu)

Comment: this seems rather nasty! I personally think you should mock the communication between the hosts in your unittests, but If you really want to do this you could also simple execute your verification script on your linux box using `ssh <user_with_ssh_key>@<remotehost> python execute_verification.py` next capture the output of this with `check_output` and verify the return value on your windows host.

Comment: @flazzarini yes, I finally decided to write my own 'stack', using ssh executed in multiple threads/processes. (parallelization is crucial in my case). after some research I found out that I would need to do that with xdist anyway (that is, writing the remote execution stack).

Comment: Okey so you could answer your own question here.

Comment: that being said, I cannot use 'fabric' for that purpose, cause it crashes when attempting to run in parrallel mode on windows (on linux, it works just fine).

Answer (score 1):

My final design utilizes ssh & multiprocessing instead of xdist (in the *execute_tc()* function):

```
import multiprocessing
import test_functions

def test_example_message(self):
"""Example test case"""
    # to get IPs, usernames, passwords, other required data
    config = get_test_config('example_message')
    # will take care of threading and executing parts
    result_dict = execute_tc(config)
    # to fail or not to fail. take care of proper reporting
    process_results(result_dict)

def execute_tc(config):
"""Execute test code in parallel"""
    # create shared results dictionary
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    result_dict = manager.dict({})
    # create processes
    processes = []
    for func, platform, args in config:
        function = getattr(test_functions, func)
        worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=[result_dict, platform, args])
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()
        processes.append(worker)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    return result_dict
```

Comment: and I've found this example particularly useful when dealing with ssh: http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2012/10/11/using-paramiko-to-send-ssh-commands/

Comment: I always find distributed/SSH integration tests to be interesting stuff (and not very well documented or blogged about). Thanks for updating.

Comment: I use SSH (Paramiko) for this. I am testing a BIG system, too big to mock, and too big to "spin-up-run-tests-and-destroy". (Instead of mocking, we have scripts that continually check or roll back the lab to a known state).  I use Paramiko (SSH) to "do things on server A, wait, then check state on server B (which consumes downstream data from A). If I were starting from scratch, I might lean towards Spur.py instead of Paramiko.

Answer (score 0):

```
def execute_tc(config):
"""Execute test code in parallel"""
    # create shared results dictionary
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    result_dict = manager.dict({})
    # create processes
    processes = []
    for func, platform, args in config:
        function = getattr(test_functions, func)
        worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=[result_dict, platform, args])
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()
        processes.append(worker)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    return result_dict
```

I think you have change the execute test case method to execute particular test cases.

Comment: the 'function' takes care of what exactly is to be executed, depending on the 'platform' parameter.

    `def test_function(result_dict, platform,[server,...]):  
         if platform == 'windows':
              result_dict['windows'] = do_sth_locally()
         else:  
              result_dict[platform] = ssh_execute('remote_func', server)`